# How to convert LF to CRLF on checkout

Tags: git

I'm trying to commit a file with CRLF line endings and have another person check it out, also with CRLF line endings.

I've got the following in `.gitattributes`:

```
* text=auto
```

When I add file with CRLF endings, I get the following message:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in test.cs
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

If I clone the repository, the file  gets cloned with LF line endings. I can override this by setting `*.cs text eol=crlf`, but that's not very supportable since I'd have to do if for every file type.

Am I misunderstanding, or shouldn't `text=auto` convert the LF back to CRLF? Is this a bug?

Is there a way to have git convert line endings back? Or, preferably, not change them at all? We are working with all CRLF files/platforms so ideally git just wouldn't touch the EOL

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying

```
* text=auto
```

in your `.gitattributes`, say

```
* text eol=crlf
```

Quoting [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings):

> **text eol=crlf**
>
> This setting tells git to normalize the files specified on commit, and
>   always convert them to CRLF on checkout. You should use this for files
>   that must retain CRLF endings, even on OSX or Linux.

Comment: If I do that, I have to either do it per-extension, or mark binary files as such, also per-extension. That's what I'm doing at the moment, but I don't like it since another dev can add a filetype I haven't considered and run into problems. Can you comment on my update made right as you posted, the line `Am I misunderstanding...`? It seems to me that `text=auto` is intended to convert LF back to CRLF if you check out on the appropriate platform.

Comment: @Turch: git does not apply the `text` setting to binary files.

Comment: @EdwardThomson but `*` tells git to apply `text eol=crlf` to all files - so I have to tell it which ones are binary, e.g. `*.dll binary`

Comment: @Turch: No.  "Git usually guesses correctly whether a blob contains text or binary data by examining the beginning of the contents." from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html

Comment: "This setting tells git to normalize the files specified on commit" - what are "files specified" if not `*`, or all files? My assumption is that the line means "All files are text files and have eol=crlf". Are you saying it is "All files *which* are text files have eol=crlf"?

Comment: @devnull Can you elaborate? The documentation even says "on checkout they are converted to the OS's native line endings" for the plain `text` setting, but when I try that, the file still gets checked out with LF on Windows, even though it was created and committed with CRLF

Comment: @Turch Yes.  It'll apply to *text* files.

Comment: @devnull So then what does the option `* text` do?